# Editing data with Jquery Mobile/PHP does not work correctly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mobile

I have created a database with some data in it. I'm already able to display the data with Jquery Mobile. The only problem is when I come to my edit page, update the data, and return to the home page, the url stays the same. Example:

I'm in example.com/index.php ---> click on a link that directs to example.com/index.php?id=1 (or any other number) --> update the data and click to return to index.php with the updated data, but the url stays at example.com/index.php?id=1 with the content of index.php. I'm confused!! This are my 2 files:

index.php

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>


<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            AmateurStandenLive
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="true" >
                 <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a">
                <h3>Oost</h3>


                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b">
                <h3>4G</h3>

                <ul data-role="listview" >
                    <?php
                try
                {
                    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","zomervak_amalive","***");
                    mysql_select_db("***", $connection);
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zattop");

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<li><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'><h2>" . $row['thuis'] . " - "  . $row['uit'] . "</h2><h3>" . $row['thuisscore'] . " - " . $row['uitscore'] . "</h3></a></li>";
                    }

                    mysql_close($connection);
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a">
                <h3>West</h3>  
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b">
                <h3>4B</h3>
      </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

edit.php

```
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?>

 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

 <table border="1">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2"><b><font color='Red'>Edit Records </font></b></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Name<em>*</em></font></b></td>
 <td><label>
 <input type="text" name="thuisscore" value="<?php echo $thuisscore; ?>" />
 </label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Address<em>*</em></font></b></td>
 <td><label>
 <input type="text" name="uitscore" value="<?php echo $uitscore; ?>" />
 </label></td>
 </tr>


 <tr align="Right">
 <td colspan="2"><label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Records">
  </label></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php
  }


 /* Database Connection */

 $sDbHost = 'localhost';
 $sDbName = '***';
 $sDbUser = 'zomervak_amalive';
 $sDbPwd = '***';

 $dbConn = mysql_connect ($sDbHost, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($sDbName,$dbConn) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{

$id = $_POST['id'];
$thuisscore = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['thuisscore']));
$uitscore = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['uitscore']));



if ($thuisscore == '' || $uitscore == '' )
{

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';


valid($id, $thuisscore, $uitscore, $error);
}
else
{

mysql_query("UPDATE zattop SET thuisscore='$thuisscore', uitscore='$uitscore' WHERE     id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());

header('Location: index.php');
}
}
else
{

echo 'Error!';
}
}
else

{

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zattop WHERE id=$id")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row)
{

$thuisscore = $row['thuisscore'];
 $uitscore = $row['uitscore'];


valid($id, $thuisscore, $uitscore,'');
}
else
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else

{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
?>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an Undefined error which means some variables have not been set.

The problem is with you input fields. The names are not set.

```
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $thuisscore; ?>"  />
     </div>

     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="name"><b>Uitteam:</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $uitscore; ?>"  />
```

Notice they both have the same name of 'name="name"' and you later ask for these as POST variables:

```
$thuisscore = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['thuisscore']));
```

$uitscore = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['uitscore']));

But they do not exist.

So try this.

```
<input type="text" name="thuisscore" id="name" value="<?php echo $thuisscore; ?>"  />
     </div>

     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="name"><b>Uitteam:</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="uitscore" id="name" value="<?php echo $uitscore; ?>"  />
```

Also at the top of your page initialise the $error variable ($error = null;)

Remember to change the redirect to view.php instead of index.php

```
header('Location: index.php'); // becomes header('Location: view.php');
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply although it didnt help me much. You can see a working example at http://www.zomervakanties2012.com/test/view.php In this file you can see the total code, with view.php en edit.php in it: http://www.zomervakanties2012.com/test/Archief.zip May be than will thing be more clear. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I haven't look at the logic of the code but straight away I can see that it is redirecting to index.php instead of view.php (line 78)

Comment: Hi Ian, I made some changes like you suggested (see the zip file), but I still get the undefined error. Any more ideas?

Comment: I checked out the zip file again, have you changed the name attribute of the inputs accordingly?

Comment: As you can see in edit.php in the zip I changed the inputs accordingly.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the validation of $_POST['id'].
Comment out everything between the braces of (if (isset($_POST['submit'])){...})and put var_dump($_POST); check everything is there.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. It is with the HTML markup of your form. The input of id if wrapped in another form tag. You need to remove the inner form elements for this to work.